# How to validate JSON in WSO2 ESB mediator?

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

Does the validate mediator validate a message payload against a JSON schema?

If validate mediator does not validate JSON against a schema, what is the best workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no native JSON schema validation support in any ESB  mediators. As a workaround, you will have to create an XSD structure as per your JSON payload and then use it in the validate mediator [1].

But however this feature is available in the road map [2].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Validate+Mediator

[2] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4640

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using filter mediators.
use filter mediators for validate required keys/values in request.

for more details about filter mediators refer the below [1] wso2 doc

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator

Comment: I don't believe your workaround meets the requirement.  The requirement is to validate a payload against an entire schema. implementing the stated workaround would require a JSON path for every leaf node.